# Cross platform testing with same browser

Tags: testing, cross-platform

Suppose we have two operating system lets say Windows 8.1 and Linux and we have the same browser on both the OS lets say, we have Firefox on both the machine. We do have a download link to download a file.
My question is that we are able to download the file from one operating system and not from the other though we have the same configuration of the browser.
Here what is the problem?

Comment: Without a more specific problem description, we cannot know. There are many possible reasons for this.

Comment: Why do you even test on linux. Almost no one uses it. Most linux installations are servers. Almost no one uses linux to browser. It less then 1% that uses a linux browser. 

Since there are 2 different OS the browsers doesnt work in the same way. If you want specific help show us the code and the error.

Comment: Please give any 2 reasons from many possible reasons.

Comment: i am not asking any particular OS, take any two different OS, take mac and windows, Now i type your answer.it was an interview question.